# one big database, or one per client?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've been asked to develop an application that will be run out to a number of business units.  the application will be the basically the same for each unit, but will have minor procedural differences, which won't change the structure of the underlying database. Should I use one database per business unit, or one big database for all the units?  The business units are totally separate

Answer (score 2):

My preference is for one database per client. The advantages:

- if a client gets too big, they're easy to move - backup, restore, change the connection string, boom. Try doing that when their data is mixed in with others in a massive database. Even if you use schemas and filegroups to segregate, moving them is not a cakewalk.
- ditto for deleting a client's data when they move on.
- by definition you're keeping each client's data separate. This is often going to be a want, and sometimes a need. Sometimes it will even be legally binding.
- all of your code within a database is simpler - it doesn't have to include the client's schema (which can't be parameterized) and your tables don't have to be littered with an extra column indicating the client.

A lot of people will claim that managing 200 or 500 databases is a lot harder than managing 10 databases. It's not really any different, in my experience. You build scripts that automate things, you stagger index maintenance and backup jobs, etc.

The potential disadvantages are when you get up into the realm of 4-digit and higher databases per instance, where you want to start thinking about having multiple servers (the threshold really depends on the workload and the hardware, so I'm just picking a number). If you build the system right, adding a second server and putting new databases there should be quite simple. Again, the app should be aware of each client's connection string, and all you're doing by using different servers is changing the instance the connection string points to.

Some questions over on dba.SE you should look at. They're not all about SQL Server, but many of the concepts and challenges are universal:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/handling-growing-number-of-tenants-in-multi-tenant-database-architecture

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/what-are-the-performance-implications-of-running-multiple-smaller-dbs-instead-of

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/one-big-database-vs-several-smaller-ones

Comment: Thanks very much Aaron, you echoed my thinking almost exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a design question.  In order to answer it, you need to understand the requirements of the system that you want to build.  From a technical perspective, SQL Server -- or really any database -- can handle either scenario.

Here are some things to think about.

The first question is how separate your clients need the data to be.  Mixing data together from different business units may not be legal in some cases (say, the investment side of a bank and the market analysis side).  In such situations, separate databases are  the solution.

The next question is security.  In some situations, clients might be very uncomfortable knowing that their data is intermixed with other clients data.  A small slip-up, and confidential information is inadvertently shared.  This is probably not an issue for different business units in the same company.

Do you have to deal with different uptime requirements, upload requirements, customizations, and perhaps interaction with other tools?  If one business unit will need customizations ASAP that other business units are not interested in, then that suggests different databases.

Another consideration is performance.  Does this application use a lot of expensive resources?  If so, being able to partition the application on different databases -- and potentially different servers -- may be highly desirable.

On the other hand, if much of the data is shared, and the repository is really a central repository with the same underlying functionality, then one database is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Gordon,  My clients are different businesses totally but in the same field, so I think 'separate but equal' databases are the answer.